# How can I eliminate the features that are highly correlated?

Tags: r, correlation, feature-selection

This is the correlations I have between the features.

```
 id      Var1      Var2      Freq
<int>   <fctr>    <fctr>     <dbl>  
1826      A         B        1.0000000  
9790      C         D        0.9992084  
7908      E         F        0.9990906  
9891      C         G        0.9980473  
7540      H         I        0.9978009  
9894      D         G        0.9975598  
7030      J         K        0.9968493  
7948      K         L        0.9968344  
6622      M         H        0.9963263  
6999      E         K        0.9962941  
...
```

How can I eliminate the ones that are highly correlated(say Freq > 0.95) with the other features? I don't want to do it manually, deciding which should be remaining, which should be going.
For example, here above C is correlated with both D and G, and K is correlated with J,L and E. So we can tell C and K should be eliminated. How can I do that with code?

Comment: Check out the `caret` package: https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#identifying-correlated-predictors

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can come up with some rules to remove features.

This removes those features which are highly co-related (`Freq > 0.95`) with 80% of the features. You can adjust the numbers based on your preference.

```
library(dplyr)
High_Freq <- 0.95
threshold <- 0.8

df %>% group_by(Var1) %>% filter(mean(Freq > High_Freq) < threshold)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using recipes package, there is a function called step_corr that removes highly correlated variables [link][1]
[1]: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/recipes/versions/0.1.12/topics/step_corr